# Not able to download stubs from maven local repository

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I am using spring-cloud-contract in my application. I have two applications, producer and consumer. from producer I am able to generate the stub and copy to my maven local repository.

From consumer side, I have added the following configuration.

```
buildscript {   
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:${springContractVerifierVersion}"
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${springIoVersion}"
}}
  dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-
  dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-
   dependencies:${springContractVerifierVersion}"
    }}

    contracts {
       packageWithBaseClasses = 'com.spe.pace.crm.gateway'
      }

      group = 'com.spe'
      version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

and my CustomerServiceTests class is as follows

```
            @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
            @SpringBootTest(classes = com.sony.pace.crm.consumer.ConsumerApplication.class)
            @AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.spe:pace-customer-gateway:+:stubs:6565"}, workOffline = true)
            @DirtiesContext
            public class CustomerServiceTests {

            @Autowired
            private CustomerService service;

        @Test
        public void shouldGetCustomerDetailsByCustomerId() {         
        String customerId="151";
        String responseString = service.getCustomerDetailsById(customerId);
        assertEquals(responseString.getFlag(),"Pace");
              }

             }
          }
```

I am getting the following error.

```
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.spe:pace-customer-gateway:jar:stubs:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444) ~[spring-cloud-contract-shade-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246) ~[spring-cloud-contract-shade-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223) ~[spring-cloud-contract-shade-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294) ~[spring-cloud-contract-shade-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherStubDownloader.unpackedJar(AetherStubDownloader.java:168) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherStubDownloader.downloadAndUnpackStubJar(AetherStubDownloader.java:221) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerFactory.createStubsFromServiceConfiguration(StubRunnerFactory.java:60) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunnerFactory.buildBatchStubRunner(BatchStubRunnerFactory.java:59) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration.batchStubRunner(StubRunnerConfiguration.java:77) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df9633dd.CGLIB$batchStubRunner$0(<generated>) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df9633dd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bf91136d.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df9633dd.batchStubRunner(<generated>) [spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.spe:pace-customer-gateway:jar:stubs:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434) ~[spring-cloud-contract-shade-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have the stub installed? Did you do `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` or `./gradlew install` ?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I did 'gradle build publishToMavenLocal' command and I can see stub.jar in my local  .m2/repository folder

Comment: Can you show the full path to the installed stub? And all the jars inside that folder?

Comment: Hi Marcin, You are absolutely correct. the jar which is in repository is having different version. apologies for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. Can you write an answer to this question so it's marked as answered?